# Java Heap Memory Settings for Tomcat 8.5 and possibles consequences

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I have a **Tomcat 8.5** installed on a **Linux virtual machine** with **16 GB RAM**.

They are **four webapps** loaded in the server (three of them are **Spring Boot Apps**). *One of those apps create large PDF and Excel reports (with Jasper Reports) and also executes scheduled task with 'medium-heavy' processing at every hour.*

I had a lot of **OutOfMemoryException** *(java heap space)*, so i updated the Tomcat configuration. This is my current jvm heap configuration *(/tomcat_dir/bin/setenv.sh)*:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

After a while, **a new OutOfMemoryException ocurred** *(this time GC overhead limit exceeded)*. So, i tried with this configuration:

```
-Xms8192m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

**The Spring Boot applications started OK, but after a while (15-30 minutes, one 'heavy-medium' scheduled task exectuion) it collapsed roundly**: *for example, datasource connections and queries crashed and extrange ssl exceptions ocurred (Could not generate DH keypair).*

**I am a bit confused about the JVM Heap managment, so my question is:
it was a bad idea to assign 8 GB of heap size? Why? What configuration do you recomend?**

If you need more information, please let me know.

Have a nice day.

Comment: First of all you should check if the memory consumption can be explained or if it happens due to an error. There are tools for examining heap dumps

Comment: Test apps one at a time. Logs could have good info too.